# How can I run an Azure Function that I deployed to run from a package file?

Tags: azure-functions

I have deployed a TimerTrigger function. It is configured to run at 3 AM my time. I want to either run it manually or review the logs from the prior morning to verify that it ran correctly.

How can I run it manually when I have deployed it with visual studio 2019 and therefore am running it from a package file? The Azure Portal functions blade doesn't offer the ability to see and modify the code or run the function when you have deployed it in this way.

Alternatively, how can I review logs from this morning? I went to the Kudu and the logstream and that's a live rendering of log output.

Answer (score 0):

As we have corn expressions in Timer Trigger function we cannot trigger function manually Alternatively we can check logs through application insights logs if you have configured or go to the monitor and check the invocation history.